# How to reverse the order of observations in a data frame with individuals that are of different lengths

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to `df` created here (but much larger and more complex):

```r
ID = c(letters[1:5])
num = c(10,12,13,9,18)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(ID, num), num = sequence(num))
```

So in this example, the individual a (`ID` a) has 10 observations (rows), individual b has 12 observations, and so on.. 
I am essentially trying to reverse the order of the observations for each individual so that the data will be structured like this:

```r
ID   num
a    10
a    9
a    8
…    … 
a    1
b    12
b    11
b    10
…    … 
b    1
c    13
…    …
```

I have tried stuff like this, which is close, but it doesn't structure it exactly like I want:

```r
df2<-
df%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  arrange(desc(num))
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `arrange` by ID as well

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    arrange(ID, desc(num))
```